# 502 Server Error: Could it be caused by the end of my free trial?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, web-development-server, server-error

My website has been up and running fine on GCP. Today, I went to visit the site and was greeted with the lovely:

> Error: Server Error The server encountered a temporary error and could
>   not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

I was surprised considering I haven't touched GCP in a while since the website has been running fine. When I visited GCP I was prompted to upgrade my account. Since my free trial expired, would my site's serve have shut down? If so, when can I expect it to be back up after upgrading my account?

Thanks,
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

You should contact Google for these types of questions or consult their published documentation. Except for Google representatives, we can only give you our opinions.

> 4. Conclusion of the Free Trial.
>
> 4.1 When the Free Trial ends, Customer will no longer have access to the Services and the Free Trial Terms and Conditions will no longer
>   apply. During the 30 day period following the conclusion of the Free
>   Trial, Customer may contact Google support (i) to migrate Customer
>   Data from the Services (other than Google Compute Engine); or (ii) to
>   upgrade to a standard Google Cloud Platform account.

[Supplemental Terms and Conditions For Google Cloud Platform Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/terms/free-trial/)